# NullReferenceException in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I am getting an unusual "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" error in this LINQ query:

```
List<UDIDInfo> d2Android = d2.Where(x.DeviceOS == (byte)DeviceOS.Android).ToList();
```

I went ahead and added a null check and am still getting the error

```
List<UDIDInfo> d2Android = d2.Where(x => x.DeviceOS != null && x.DeviceOS == (byte)DeviceOS.Android).ToList();
```

Note that `(byte)DeviceOS.Android` and `d2` are both not null

Edit (Solution):

```
List<UDIDInfo> d2Android = d2.Where(x => x != null && x.DeviceOS != null && x.DeviceOS == (byte)DeviceOS.Android).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure it's linq-to-entities? What type is `d2`?

Comment: If `d2` is null, what do you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What if `x` is null? That is, the enumerable `d2` contains a `null` item.

Try the following. You shouldn't get any null reference exception.

```
List<UDIDInfo> d2Android = d2
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Where(x => x.DeviceOS != null)
    .Where(x => x.DeviceOS == (byte)DeviceOS.Android)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If this is Linq-to-entities, then x can't be null.

Comment: @user2674389 That's probably true. I didn't even notice the LINQ-to-entities tag since there was no mention in the question.

Comment: Actually Tim's method worked; adding x != null short circuits the query. d2 is a List<T>

Comment: @OmarMeky Then the tag ***EntityFramework*** is wrong, since there is nothing related to EntityFramework.

Comment: Fair enough, I added it since the List came from an EF query but that's irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

avoid the argument null exception in LINQ like below

```
Summaries = (from r in Summaries
          where r.Contains(SearchTerm)
          orderby r
          select r).ToArray();
```

In this case, if null passed to searchTerm you can check the null expression like below

```
Summaries = (from r in Summaries
          where string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm) ||r.Contains(SearchTerm)
          orderby r
          select r).ToArray();
```